# Is there a way to use tensorflow with java on 32bit windows machines?

Tags: java, tensorflow, java-native-interface

I have a program which uses the Tensorflow Java Lib. I downloaded the JNI Library but it only works on 64bit machines. Is there an other Tensorflow JNI Library for 32 bit Windows machines?

Comment: You can download [sources from github](https://github.com/tensorflow) and build it for x86 architecture

Answer (score 0):

There is not a TensorFlow JNI Library for 32-bit Windows machines.